# Azure IoT Edge Support for JSON Arrays in Device Twin

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

Microsoft seems to have recently added support for JSON Array fields in the [Device Twin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins). I can successfully set an array as a desired property and can receive and parse it on my device. However, when I try to generate a reported property in array form and send this from my device back to the cloud, it fails with a 400 error.

I am using version 0.2.0.0-26xenial of the Azure IoT C SDK to implement an `IoTHubDeviceClient` and then using `IoTHubDeviceClient_SendReportedState()` to send updates to the reported properties.

What is the latest on support for JSON arrays in the device twin?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your C-SDK to 0.2.0.0-27xenial for this.

For reference, here is the commit that updated the API version to enable this feature:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/commit/6f5632ca2ca18da9c786095faa9037a32800cf2b